# Why are media files not being loading

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

I'm writting a web site which has api backend part and frontend part. I do not write a frontend part. And frontend is heavily tested and should be work fine. So the problem is with my backend.
Media files are being loaded in docker container (checked) but are not being loaded in website (localhost). I have no 404's. It looks like there is no requests to media files on website.

global urls:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    )
```

settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media_backend/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'backend_media')
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    location /static_backend/ {
        alias /app/backend_static/;
    }
    location /static/admin {
        alias /app/backend_static/admin/;
    }
    location /media_backend/ {
        alias /app/backend_media/;
    }
    location /api/docs/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/redoc.html;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8000/admin/;
    }
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  backend:
    image: konstantin05/foodgram_backend:latest
    expose:
      - 8000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_value:/app/backend_static/
      - media_value:/app/backend_media/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.3-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ../frontend/build:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ../docs/redoc.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/api/docs/redoc.html
      - ../docs/openapi-schema.yml:/usr/share/nginx/html/api/docs/openapi-schema.yml
      - static_value:/app/backend_static/
      - media_value:/app/backend_media/
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    frontend:
      image: konstantin05/foodgram_frontend:latest
      volumes:
        - ../frontend/:/app/result_build/
volumes:
  static_value:
  media_value:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
volumes:
      - static_value:/app/backend_static/
      - media_value:/app/backend_media/
```

Try this way:

```
volumes:
      - dev-static-data:/vol/web  #I have removed media_value from volumes
```

And in your settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'
```

Do above things only in docker compose and settings.py file.

And see if this is solves?

Comment: Thank you. I changed this but media still has not being loading

Comment: also remove forward slash from nginx image

Comment: I deleted slash at nginx volumes static-value and media-value when you wrote me for the first time. It didn't helped me. I also changed folder to web and this thing has no effect (I added record with image after changing it)

Comment: Unfortunately it takes no effect

Comment: The problem was in strange urls of media. I added:     def get_image(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url  to serializer